# delete a line based on logic

Tags: python, text-processing

I have a file where i have multiple records  with such data

> F00DY4302B8JRQ rank=0000030 x=800.0 y=1412.0 length=89

now i want to search for the line where  if i find  length<=50 then delete this line and the next line in the file and write to another file.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head:

```
for every line in file
split by spaces
get last token
split by equal
verify length
write line to another file
delete line and the next
```

Hope this is what you need to start working.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Python 2.6 (let us know if it's another version you need!), and that you want to skip *every* line with length <= 50 (and ignore the next line in each case), if any:

```
import re

def weirdtask(infname, oufname):
  inf = open(infname, 'r')
  ouf = open(oufname, 'w')
  rle = re.compile(r'length=\s*(\d+)')
  for line in inf:
    mo = re.search(line)
    if mo:
      thelen = int(mo.group(1))
      if thelen <= 50:
        next(inf)
        continue
    ouf.write(line)
  ouf.close()
```

If that's not exactly your specs, please clarify.

```
  inf.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are always in the same order and there are always the same number, you can just use the `.split()` method on the string, and find the one you want with an index:

```
words = line.split()
l = words[4]
temp = l.split("=")[2]
if int(temp) <= 50:
    # found the line, handle it
    do_something_here()
```

If the columns might be in any order, you could use regular expressions.

```
s_pat = "length\s*=\s*(\d+)"
pat = re.compile(s_pat)

m = pat.search(line)
if m:
    temp = m.group(1)
    if int(temp) <= 50:
        # found the line, handle it
        do_something_here()
```

This uses the "match group" from the regular expression to grab the number.

P.S. Two answers appeared while I was writing this.  I am not the fastest gun in the west.

Comment: Can't afford the stagecoach fare.